# Say $K=\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$. Determine all endomorphisms of $K$.

Tags: field-theory, abstract-algebra

> Say $K=\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$. Determine all endomorphisms of $K$, and justify your answer.

Hint: Say $f(x)= x^3-2$. How many roots of $f$ are in $K$?

For this I know $x^3-2$ has 1 real root, $2^{1/3}$, and 2 complex roots, $(-(2i)^{1/3})$ and $(-1)^{2/3}(2^{1/3}$, but I don't know which are morphisms in $K$. Can someone help, please and explain it to me?

Comment: By "morphism", they mean a homomorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ element-wise. So $2^{1/3}$ must be mapped to another root of $x^3-2$, of which there is only one. Hence, the identity is the only morphism.

Answer (score 0):

Any endomorphism $\phi$ of $K$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is fully determined by what it does to $\sqrt[3]{2}$ (since the field is generated by this element).

However since $\sqrt[3]{2}^3 = 2$ we find that $\phi(\sqrt[3]{2})^3 = 2$

Hence $\phi(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is also a root of $x^3 - 2$ (just as $\sqrt[3]{2}$ was).

However since $\phi$ is an endomorphism of $K$ we must have that $\phi(\sqrt[3]{2})\in K$.

Since $K$ is a subfield of the real numbers and two of the roots of $x^3 - 2$ are complex we must have that $\phi(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \sqrt[3]{2}$ so that $\phi$ is the identity map.